# Print reverse Array = Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

Saw that the error may occur when you try to access empty memory but it seems like I definied my 'for loops' well so I'm pretty much stuck here..

```
int main () {

    int size, arr[size];

    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", size);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("In normal order: \n");

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        printf("|%d|\n", arr[j]);
    }

    printf("In reverse order: ");

    for (int k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        printf("|%d|\n", arr[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about the *order* in which you do things... What is the value of `size` when you define the array? When and where do you thing the array is defined?

Answer (score 1):

`int size, arr[size];` doesn't make sense. For some reason this bug is surprisingly common. See this FAQ on Codidact: [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440) To quote the initial part of that post:

> C programs are executed from top to bottom. You can't declare a VLA with an uninitialized variable as its size parameter. For the same reason at you can't do this:
>
> ```
> int x;
> printf("%d\n",x);
> scanf("%d",&x);
> ```
>
> If I type `5` as input to this program, then it doesn't magically go back and change the `printf` to print `5`. Because it is already too late - I took input *after* I printed.
>
> Similarly, `int array[size];` doesn't create some magic bond between `array` and `size`. The array gets created to be as large as the value that `size` had at the point where that source code line was encountered. If `size` is uninitialized, then you get undefined behavior. Changing `size` afterwards does not change the size of the VLA. And you can't resize a VLA either.